# From RLC prototype to signal flow graph

Tags: capacitor, operational-amplifier, filter, circuit-analysis, impedance

This simple 3rd order low-pass circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff1cBC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

can be described with the following 3 equations:

$$-V_1 = \displaystyle \frac{-1}{sC_1} \left( \displaystyle \frac{V_{in} - V_1}{R_S} - I_2 \right)$$

$$-I_2 = \displaystyle \frac{-1}{sL_2} \left( \displaystyle V_1 - V_3 \right)$$

$$V_3 = \displaystyle \frac{-1}{sC_3} \left( -I_2 + \displaystyle \frac{V_3}{R_L} \right)$$

It can be realized through an active-RC filter using integrators and so opamps. The resulting signal flow graph should be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYgaBd.png)</sup>

Note that \$ I_2 \$ is a voltage value and not a current. The values or numbers alongside of the branches are their transfer functions.

Suppose that it is possible to realize the negative resistances corresponding to the right-hand side branches. The active RC realization is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr3poS.png)</sup>

Each integrator is realized with an opamp circuit; it is assumed that the input signals of each integrator are *currents* and the outputs are *voltages*.

It is explicitly specified in the [book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471097977.html) that the second stage is a *non-inverting* integrator (realized through the negative resistances of the right-hand side branches, so that the minus sign in its transfer function is cancelled by the minus sign of these resistances).

So, why is it used the equation

$$-I_2 = \displaystyle \frac{-1}{sL_2} \left( \displaystyle V_1 - V_3 \right)$$

instead of

$$I_2 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{sL_2} \left( \displaystyle V_1 - V_3 \right)$$

?

As stated in the comments, I think there is no correspondance between the equations, the signal flow graph and the realization with opamps:

- if the second block is a non-inverting integrator, in the signal flow graph its transfer function should be \$ 1 / sL_2 \$ instead of \$ - 1 / sL_2 \$; the output should be \$ I_2 \$ instead of \$ -I_2 \$ and the resistances on the left-hand braces should both be \$ -1 \$ (so, even if the signal flow graph can perform only summation, it is possible to *subtract* \$ I_2 \$ in the first and in the third stage);
- the active RC circuit *doesn't* exactly realize the signal flow graph: its second stage is a *non-inverting* integrator (while in the signal flow graph it appears as inverting) but it realizes the positive left-hand braces resistances.

Did I make some mistakes or is the circuit built in a wrong manner?

Comment: That's because I2 has to be subtracted from Vin and the flow graph only makes use of summing blocks. That's why the transfer function is -1/sL2. Not because both equations are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: The two equations are identical as far as I can see.

Comment: @Ambiorix You are right about the summing nodes. But there is no correspondace between the signal flow graph and the realization: that is, the output of the second opamp is *actually* \$ [ 1/(sL_2) ] (V_1 - V_3) \$ due to the negative resistors. So, it is \$ I_2 \$ and *not* \$ - I_2 \$. My question is: why?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, the equations are identical, but they define two different circuits. The former equation, with both minus sign, states that there is an **inverting** integrator; the latter states that there is a **non-inverting** integrator. The former agrees with the signal flow graph but (in my opinion) not with the realization with opamps; the latter agrees with the realization with opamps but not with the signal flow graph. What's wrong?